Principal eigenfunction of $\Delta$ on rectangular patch of $S^d$
Let $S^d \subset \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ be the unit sphere. Using $d+1$-dimensional spherical coordinates, fix $$\begin{align*} 0 \leq \varphi_{1,1} &< \varphi_{1,2} \leq 2\pi \\0 \leq \varphi_{2,1} &< \varphi_{2,2} \leq \pi  \\ \vdots \\ 0 \leq \varphi_{d,1} &< \varphi_{d,2} \leq \pi \end{align*}$$
and define the "rectangular" subregion $$D:=\Phi[(\varphi_{1,1}, \varphi_{1,2}) \times \cdots \times (\varphi_{d,1}, \varphi_{d,2})] \subset S^d$$ as the image of the box under the spherical coordinates $\Phi$. (An example would be a spherical quadrangle on $S^2$ restricted by lines of latitude and longitude.)

Is there an explicit representation of the principal eigenfunction (i.e. with highest nonzero eigenvalue) of the Laplacian $\Delta_D$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions?

Some thoughts:

I tried to mimic the various derivations of the spherical harmonics (for the whole sphere). They all refer to concepts (harmonic polynomials, Legendre, Gegenbauer equation) which I was not able to transform from the unit interval with the condition of periodicity to an arbitrary interval with Dirichlet boundary conditions. For example one prominent way is to recursively express $\Delta_{S^k}$ via $\Delta_{S^{k-1}}$, separate variables $u(\varphi_1, \dots, \varphi_d)=\prod u_k(\varphi_k)$ and obtain (for example here) the ODEs $\Delta_{S^1} u_1 = \partial_1^2 u_1 = -\lambda_1 u_1$ (solvable) and $$\partial_k^2 u_k + (k-1) \textrm{cot}(\varphi_k) \partial_k u_k + \left( \lambda_k - \frac{\lambda_{k-1}}{\sin^2 \varphi_k} \right) u_k = 0$$ For this ODE I then only find the above mentioned Legendre/Gegenbauer solution.
The derivation of this might be easier than having to present a complete eigenfunction basis since we are only looking for the principal eigenfunction.
There is a theory on the harmonics of a spherical cap. This seems to be a step in the right direction since it is defined by restricting the first angular variable. Unfortunately, I could not access the original paper ...


For a hypercube with boundaries  not equal to the periodicities or poles,  both independent solutions of the chain of hypergeometric equations (after $\cos \theta_i  \to z_i \in (-1,1))$ have to be combined to satisfy both  boundary conditons of its interval. That implies the second solution  with a logarithmic singularity iirc.

@RolandF Could you elaborate this a bit further, maybe with an example on $S^2$?

As a not so trivial example take hyperspherical coordinates in $\mathbb R^4$. I use Mathematica for short
$$\text{SeparatedLaplacian}(1)=\text{Expand}\left[ \frac{1}{R(r)\ \Theta (\theta ) R(r) \Psi (\psi ) \Phi (\phi )} \ \text{Laplacian}[R(r) \ \Theta (\theta )\ \Psi (\psi ) \ \Phi (\phi ), \{r,\ \theta ,\ \phi ,\ \psi \},\{\text{Hyperspherical},4\}]\right]=0$$
with the separating form in steps backwards
$$\frac{\frac{\Theta ''(\theta )+2 \cot (\theta ) \Theta '(\theta )}{\Theta (\theta )}+\frac{\frac{\Phi ''(\phi )+\cot (\phi ) \Phi '(\phi )}{\Phi (\phi )}+\frac{\Psi ''(\psi )}{\Psi (\psi ) \sin ^2(\phi )}}{\sin ^2(\theta )}}{r^2}+\frac{R''(r)+\frac{3 R'(r)}{r}}{R(r)}=0$$
Start with the eigenvalue equation for $\Psi(\psi )$
$$\text{Simplify}\left[\frac{\Psi ''(\psi )}{\Psi (\psi )}=-m^2\ \text{/.} \ \, \left\{\Psi \to \left( \psi \to \left(a \sin(m \psi)+b \cos(m \psi)\right)\right)\right\}\right]$$
If  the intervall is a full circle, $m$ is an an integer and $a = i b$ yields periodic eigenfunctions of $-i\partial_\psi$ For any other finite interval  $l < 2\pi,$ a linear combination of real functions with zeros on the boundaries is the solution in $\mathit L^2(a,a+l)$ and $ m \ l = n \ \pi, n \in \mathbb Z $  is the quantisation condition.
Replacing the operator with the eigenvalue, the reduced Laplacian is
$$\text{SeparatedLaplacian}(2)=\text{Expand}\left[\text{SeparatedLaplacian}(1)\text{/.}\, \left\{\Psi \to \left( \psi \to e^{i\ m \ \psi}\right)\right\}\right]$$
$$\frac{\frac{\Theta ''(\theta )+2 \cot (\theta ) \Theta '(\theta )}{\Theta (\theta )}+\frac{\frac{\Phi ''(\phi )+\cot (\phi ) \Phi '(\phi )}{\Phi (\phi )}+\frac{-m^2}{\sin ^2(\phi )}}{\sin ^2(\theta )}}{r^2}+\frac{R''(r)+\frac{3 R'(r)}{r}}{R(r)}=0$$
The next equation to solve is the Legendre equation known from $\mathit S^2$
$$\text{DSolveValue}\left[m^2 \Phi (\phi ) \csc ^2(\phi )-\Phi ''(\phi )-\cot (\phi ) \Phi '(\phi )=l (l+1) \Phi (\phi ),\Phi ,\phi \right]$$
$$\{\phi \}\to c_1 P_l^m(\cos (\phi ))+c_2 Q_l^m(\cos (\phi ))$$
Here $m$ is not an integer and l is not an integer too, again for an arbitrary interval, both general associated Legendre functions have to be combined to yield zeros at the boundary, the reflection condition in quantum theory.
Again replacing the operator by its eigenvalue
$$\text{SeparatedLaplacian}(2)\text{/.}\, \Phi ''(\phi ):\to -l (l+1) \Phi (\phi )+m^2 \Phi (\phi ) \csc ^2(\phi )-\cot (\phi ) \Phi '(\phi )$$
yields finally the two eigenvalue equations of second order, eigenvalues depending on the intervals
$$\frac{-\Theta ''(\theta )-2 \cot (\theta ) \Theta '(\theta )+\frac{(l+1) l \Theta (\theta )}{\sin ^2(\theta )}}{\Theta (\theta )}=\frac{r \left(r R''(r)+3 R'(r)\right)}{R(r)}$$
$$\text{DSolveValue}\left[-\Theta ''(\theta )-2 \cot (\theta ) \Theta '(\theta )+(l+1) l \Theta (\theta ) \csc ^2(\theta )=\left(\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-1\right) \Theta (\theta ),\Theta ,\theta \right]$$
The solutions are general associated Legendre functions of $\cos \theta$ with factors of fractional powers of $\sin \theta$
$$\theta \to\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin \theta}} \left( c_1 P_p^{\frac{1}{2} (2 l+1)}(\cos (\theta )) + c_2 Q_p^{\frac{1}{2} (2 l+1)}(\cos (\theta )\right)$$
